# Equation of a Chord to a Circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

If equation of a origin centered $\mathcal circle$  with radius $3$ is $x^2+y^2=9$, what is the $\pmb {equation}$ $\pmb{of ~ the ~chord}$ to this circle which is divided internally by the point $P \equiv (1,2)$ in the ratio $\color{blue} 1: \color{red} 2$?

I've been trying to solve this problem as it appears in my textbook's Circle chapter.

### My Attempts

---

I used section formula and found out if point $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2)$ is the endpoints of the chord $\mathbf {AB}$ `(which is also the intersection of the chord and the circle)` then using **section formula** for internal division yields $$\frac{1 \cdot x_2 +2 \cdot x_1}{1+2}=1 \implies 2x_1+x_2=3 \implies x_1+x_2=3- x_1 \qquad (1) $$ and $$ \frac{1 \cdot y_2 +2 \cdot y_1}{1+2} =2 \implies 2y_1+y_2=6  \implies y_1+y_2=6- y_1 \qquad (2) $$ as the point $P(1,2)$ divides the segment (chord) $\mathbf {AB}$ in the ratio $\color{blue} 1: \color{red} 2$ . In the next step, I let the equation of the chord to be $y-2=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1 -x_2}(x-1)$ as it passes through the point $P(1,2)$ and $A(x_1, y_1)$, $B(x_2, y_2)$. Then if the center of the circle `(which is also the origin)` is $O(0, 0)$ the distance $OA$ and $OB$ should be the same as they are the radius of the circle. So, $$ OA^2 = OB^2 \implies x_1^{2} +y_1^{2} = x_2^{2} +y_2^{2} \\ \implies x_1^{2} - x_2^{2} = -(y_1^{2} -y_2^{2}) \\ \implies (x_1 +x_2)(x_1 -x_2)=-(y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2) \\ \implies \frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1 -x_2} = - \frac{x_1 +x_2}{y_1+y_2} $$
Now, if I plug in the values from $(1)$ and $(2)$ then it becomes- $$\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1 -x_2} = - \frac{3- x_1}{6- y_1}$$
Now, putting it in the equation of the chord $y-2=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1 -x_2}(x-1)$ gives $$y-2=-\frac{3- x_1}{6- y_1} (x-1)$$ Sadly I have $x_1$ and $y_1$ left in my equation.

> Was my stride taking me some places or should I change my viewpoint to this particular problem? To be honest, I really can not proceed any further. Please provide
> some help.

Comment: There is an equation for the chord length:[here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)).

Comment: @TymaGaidash, I need the equation of the chord itself. As you can see, The points that the chords intersects the circle is not given, so regular strides isn't a strategy here.

Comment: Great stuff, +1. Looks magnificent. I'm really happy for you, keep it up.

Comment: You can do this graphically by constructing a second circle, with center $\left(\frac32, 3\right)$ (so that it is half as far from $(1, 2)$ as the origin), with radius $\frac32$ (so that it is half as large by radius as the original circle).  The points of intersection of the two circles each represent one endpoint of a chord that is cut in a $1:2$ ratio by the point $(1, 2)$.  (See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ju0gitoben).)

Comment: @BrianTung, nice work. But can you explain why is that true?

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon: If you draw a line segment from any point on the new red circle, through the green point $(2, 1)$, and extend it till it intersects the original black circle, then $(2, 1)$ cuts that line segment in a $1:2$ ratio.  (Can you see why?)  But only where the starting point is also on the black circle—where the circles intersect—is this line segment actually a chord of the circle.

Comment: @BrianTung, I understood everything but "$P(1,2)$ cuts that line segment in a $1:2$ ratio" I cannot get why. I feel like it should cut in 1:2 ratio, but cannot convince myself why. I suppose it has something to do with taking a point that is half as far from $(1,2)$ as the origin and draw a circle with half of the original radius. I am really curious to know how you did that and if you applied **homothety** here.

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon: You have it exactly right.

Comment: @BrianTung, could you please describe briefly how you did that? (even if you used homothety, as it helps determining ratios, what was the center of homothety? I learnt about it, and can appreciate the mathematics constructed through this transformation but cannot do myself) as your work at least I find much brilliant and I want to think like you think of this problem.

Comment: The center would be the point $(1, 2)$ (yes, not $(2, 1)$ as I wrote earlier).  To be honest, I'd never heard the term "homothety" until you brought it up, but that is essentially what I did, yes.

Answer (score 3):

From 1) and 2) you got
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Now add the condition that A,B are on the circle
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,2} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,2} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad \left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {3 - 2x_{\,1} } \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {6 - 2y_{\,1} } \right)^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr 
  9 + 4x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  - 12x_{\,1}  + 36 + 4y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  - 24y_{\,1}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr 
  36 - 12x_{\,1}  - 24y_{\,1}  + 36 = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + 2y_{\,1}  = 6 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  2x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  = 3 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  2y_{\,1}  + x_{\,1}  = 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  x_{\,2}  = 3 - 2x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  = 3 - {{x_{\,1} } \over 2} \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,2}  = x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + y_{\,1} ^{\,2}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad \left\{ \matrix{
  x_{\,2}  = 3 - 2x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  = 3 - {{x_{\,1} } \over 2} \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,2}  = x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1} ^{\,2}  + 9 + {{x_{\,1} ^{\,2} } \over 4} - 3x_{\,1}  = 9 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  x_{\,2}  = 3 - 2x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  = 3 - {{x_{\,1} } \over 2} \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,2}  = x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  \left( {{5 \over 4}x_{\,1}  - 3} \right)x_{\,1}  = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

I suppose you can conclude from here

Comment: How can I put that in$ (1) \text{and} (2)$ equation?

Comment: sorry, you actually put it .. I overlooked that

Comment: I corrected for that

Comment: Oh jeez, I didn't see that this answer was there. My bad.

Comment: @Buraian, When you started writing it wasn't here. However, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GCab +1.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the problem is that you equated the two evaluated circle equations like so : $$x_1^2 +y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2$$

This made you lose out a bit of information. To recover, it reintroduce this condition:

$$ x_1^2 + y_1^2 =1 \tag{1}$$
$$x_2^2 + y_2^2=1 \tag{2}$$

We also have,

$$ 2x_1 + x_2=3 \tag{3}$$

$$ 2y_1 + y_2=6 \tag{4}$$

Our goal is to get an expression for $x_1$ and $y_1$, the best way to do it is to isolate for $x_2 $ and $y_2$ in (3) and (4)  and plug those back into $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$ x_2 = 3-2x_1\tag{5}$$

and,

$$ y_2=3-2y_1 \tag{6}$$

Plugging these into (2):

$$ (3-2x_1)^2 + (3-2y_1)^2 = 1$$

$$ 9+ 4x_1^2 -12x_1 + 9 + 4y_1^2 -12y_1 = 1$$

Or,

$$ 17 + 4(x_1^2 + y_1^2) -12(x_1 + y_1)=0$$

Applying equation $(1)$:

$$ 21 - 12 (x_1 + y_1)=0$$

$$ \frac{7}{4} = x_1 + y_1 \tag{7}$$

Now, equation (7) and (1) can be taken together to solve for $x_1$ and $y_1$

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
\cases{
A = (x_a,y_a)\\
B = (x_b,y_b)\\
C = (0,0)\\
P = (1,2)\\
r = 3\\
\lambda = 2\\
}
$$

we have the relations

$$
\cases{
\lambda(P-B) = A-P\\
\|A-C\|^2= r^2\\
\|B-C\|^2= r^2\\
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
2(1-x_b)+1-x_a=0\\ 2(2-y_b)+2-y_a=0\\ x_a^2+y_a^2=9\\ x_b^2+y_b^2=9
}
$$

Four equations and four unknowns. Follows a plot showing (in red) the two solutions

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time resolving it. But as it turns out, this is exactly what I concluded up there in my question. If I simplify $$2(1-x_b)+1-x_a=0 \implies x_a +2x_b=3$$ and  $$2(2-y_b)+2-y_a=0 \implies y_a +2y_b=6$$
certainly if I call $(x_a, y_a)=(x_2, y_2) ~ \text {and}~ (x_b, y_b)=(x_1, y_1)$ then it becomes $$ x_2 +2x_1=3$$ and $$ y_2 +2y_1=6$$ which is exactly what I wrote  on my equation $(1) \text{and} (2)$. However this is where the problem started back  then. Your graphical description is good, noteworthy. But I am only looking for mathematical solution for academic prpse.